# How can I make sure that the service still works if the app is closed?

Tags: android

I have an app that I want to open an activity every three minutes, and when the app is open or in recent app, this was done correctly, but when the app exits from recent app, it no longer works.
Even I have set an alarm to check every ten minutes that if the service is closed it will run again but it does not seem to work.

this is my service code:

public class SampleService extends JobService {

```
Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
private Timer timer;
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params ) {
        alarm.setAlarm(this);
        start();
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob( JobParameters params ) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service stop!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
private TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SampleService.this, SplashScreen.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
public void start() {
    if(timer != null) {
        return;
    }
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 180000, 180000);
}
public void stop() {
    timer.cancel();
    timer = null;
}
}
```

and this is my Alarm code:

public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver{

```
private JobScheduler jobScheduler;
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    @SuppressLint("InvalidWakeLockTag") PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK , "");
    wl.acquire();

    if (!isMyServiceRunning(SampleService.class , context)){
        jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

        ComponentName serviceName = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                SampleService.class.getName());

        JobInfo.Builder jobBuilder = new JobInfo.Builder(10, serviceName);

        JobInfo myJobInfo = jobBuilder.build();
        jobScheduler.schedule(myJobInfo);

        Toast.makeText(context, "12345", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

    wl.release();
}
public void setAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
}

public void cancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}

private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass , Context context) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Does anyone know what I should do to fix this?

Comment: use logcat of AndroidStudio

Comment: and what I should look for? there is no error or stops or anything that can help me

Comment: like this  :            String TAG="Your TAG NAME"; // add in service class
                           Log.d(TAG, "services of running ... ");

Answer (score 0):

**Use foreground service for Running in the background .**
write your code in the onstartCommand for oppening the activity.
or u can also set the alarm that fires every 3 minitues and start service that open the activity .

```
public class ForegroundService extends Service {
public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundServiceChannel";
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
    createNotificationChannel();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent, 0);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
            .setContentText(input)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
    startForeground(1, notification);
    //do heavy work on a background thread
    //stopSelf();
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Foreground Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        );
        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
    }
}
}
```

**for starting the service**

```
 public void startService() {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", "Foreground Service Example in 
Android");
    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);
}
```

**for stopping the service**

```
public void stopService() {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
    stopService(serviceIntent);
}
```

Comment: I tried this before, but again when the app exits from recent apps it cant open activity

Comment: Android 10 (API level 29) and higher place restrictions on when apps can start activities when the app is running in the background. ...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Answer (score 0):

It might be a limitation of starting a service in background, from [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)

> Prior to Android 8.0, the usual way to create a foreground service was
> to create a background service, then promote that service to the
> foreground. With Android 8.0, there is a complication; the system
> doesn't allow a background app to create a background service. For
> this reason, Android 8.0 introduces the new method
> startForegroundService() to start a new service in the foreground.
> After the system has created the service, the app has five seconds to
> call the service's startForeground() method to show the new service's
> user-visible notification. If the app does not call startForeground()
> within the time limit, the system stops the service and declares the
> app to be ANR.

Taking this consideration you can write the foreground service solution(@Nikit answer), or you can explore for an [Android Bounded Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services) too.

Another option is [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) with a [PeriodicWorker](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#schedule_periodic_work), just take into consideration that you have a restriction of 15 mins of minimum periodic time.